# How to test in Ruby/Rails if method has been called in class body?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I can't figure how to test class method calls from within the class body.

How can I test it?

```
class User
  act_as_paranoid
end


it 'is called from class body' do
  expect(User).to receive(:acts_as_paranoid)
  User.new
end
```

Comment: why on earth do you need this test? If the method is defined it will be called.  If not, you will get an exception.  Otherwise you're  trying to test core ruby.

Comment: Well, just to make sure it's called. There was a class where I forgot to add it and got in some trouble.

Comment: Test the difference for both cases, the successful one should differ from the one where the method isn't being called.

Comment: @SeanMagyar see updated answer.

Comment: @SebastianPalma how do you determine which classes should use that module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's usually recommended to test the behavior, not the implementation. In this case, whatever `acts_as_paranoid` *provides* for this class in terms of behavior, is what you want to test.

However, if you trust that calling `acts_as_paranoid` correctly provides all the behavior you need and just want to test that it is added to the class, you can use:

```
assert User.included_modules.include? ActsAsParanoid::Core
```

To figure this out I just briefly looked at the source code for acts_as_paranoid here: https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid/blob/master/lib/acts_as_paranoid.rb#L8

You can see that on line 50, it extends the ActsAsParanoid module to ActiveRecord::Base, which gives the model classes access to the `acts_as_paranoid` method. And if you look at the definition of this method, you can see it calls `include ActsAsParanoid::Core`

Comment: I don't wanna test the behavior as it is a gem and it's tested already. I just wanna make sure I use it for the classes I want. I could make it work with`User.included_modules`. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I was too lazy to look that up.  But yeah, these string type methods are voodoo that basically include modules. Good answer here and proof why it's good to contribute to S.O. , always learning something new!

Answer (score 1):

### Updated

This is not the greatest way to do this but if you must this is closer to what you want:

```
describe 'Check if a string method is in a file' do
  it 'matches a string pattern' do
    lines = File.read('user.rb').split("\n")
    assert lines[1][/\b+acts_as_paranoid/]
    #hacky way to make sure you don't accidentally comment it out
    assert lines[1].split('#').count == 1 
  end
end
```

Original answer:

There is nothing here to test.  Your class definition is invalid unless your method is defined when `user.rb` file loads. That is core ruby.  Prove it.

```
#user_spec.rb
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative 'user'

describe 'User' do
  it 'is a valid class' do
    assert User
  end
end

#user.rb
class User
  acts_as_paranoid
end
```

If `acts_as_paranoid` is not defined before ruby loads user.rb, spec fails as soon as the file is required. If this is all the code you have this test fails.  Comment out `acts_as_paranoid` test will pass.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The other answer seems to be cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

To just test that you added `acts_as_paranoid` to `User`, you can do:

`it 'has acts_as_paranoid' do
  expect(User).to respond_to(:acts_as_paranoid)
end`

Comment: It responds of course, but that doesn't mean it's been called.

Comment: It only 'responds' _if_ added to the `User` model. And if added, it will be executed.

Comment: Not true. It's defined on the class Class -> `User.class => Class`. So it will look it up on the inheritance chain when it comes to `respond_to?` and it's gonna return true. But that doesn't mean it's been called.

Comment: yeah, as long as you require the acts_as_paranoid gem in the application, defininng the class just as `class User < ActiveRecord::Base; end`would still let this test pass, which is not what OP wants. But, welcome to StackOverflow regardless :)